# cURL -u tag, but for SETOPT in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I need to authenticate a cURL request. In the docs, they tell me to use

```
curl https://url.com -u username:password
```

So, now I want to do this using curl_setopt(), but I cannot figure out what option the `-u` is.

For `-H` the equivilant would be the following to set headers, example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

But for `-u`, I cannot figure out the option. Ive tried looking in [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and [Linux Commands](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/curl.htm)

None of theese have helped me further.

I have tried:

```
$auth = 'foobar:pass1234';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, $auth);
```

But this doesn't seem to work, and in [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) they say that it only takes username, and not password aswell (As it says it should for `-u` in [Linux Commands](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/curl.htm).

Comment: Yes it does. I did search here on SO, but didnt find it. But this is fine, thanks :)